# .val() to .text() using/with closest and find

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to convert `.val()` to `.text()` vice-versa.

I really don't know where did I go wrong.

```
$('#result').on('click','.update',function() {
    var valval = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text(valval);
});
```

And there's the link so I hope you open it first. I will appreciate any answer that can help me with my work.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/595/).

Comment: Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/J7m7m/596/)

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').val(); it's giving null

Comment: You need to write like this $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').find("input").val();

Comment: wow., i see., hmm., nice., thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the `input` element, now you are calling `.val()` on a `td` element

```js
$(function() {
  $('#result').on('click', '.update', function() {
    var $td = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)'),
      $input = $td.find('input');

    if ($input.length) {
      $td.text($input.val());
    } else {
      $td.html($('<input />', {
        value: $td.text()
      }))
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' id='result'>
  <tr>
    <td>hi there</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' value="hello there" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class='update'>update</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hi there</td>
    <td>hello there</td>
    <td>
      <button class='update'>update</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is meant to return the value attribute of form input fields. You need to target the input field, or use `text()` on the first statement in place of val();

```
var valval = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val();
```

or

```
var valval = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

Comment: god! men, tsk., so what i'm missing is the "input" only after "td:eq(1)"

very very nice! thanks

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is used for form elements

instead of `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').val();`
you can use `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val();` or `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val()`